# Vimeo iframes for Toolset Post Archives

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video-streaming

Essentially the Iframe from the Vimeo embed link does work individually, however, I am working on a global editor for displaying all posts. using javascript seems to be the only answer, but if someone knows a way to use a simple `<video></video>` tag with a Vimeo URL let me know.

Here is what I have

```
[wpv-post-date]
[types field='date'][/types]
[types field='bible-passage'][/types]
[types field='mp3'][/types]

<div class="audio-player"><div id="play-btn"></div><div class="audio-
wrapper" id="player-container" href="javascript:;"><audio 
id="player"><source src="[types field='mp3' output='raw'][/types]">
</audio></div></div><a class="x-btn black-button x-btn-global sermon-
button sermon-audio" href="[types field='mp3' output='raw'][/types]" 
target="_blank">Download</a>
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/229578292?
title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" 
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p><a href="[types field='video'][/types]">You Shall Not Steal</a> 
from <a href="https://vimeo.com/tomballbible">Tomball Bible 
Church</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
[wpv-post-featured-image]
[types field='sermon-image'][/types]
[wpv-post-taxonomy type="preacher" separator=", " format="link" 
show="name" order="asc"]
```

The first source for the Vimeo player needs to remain in that format however the number at the end needs to change.

The "video" field has the auto-generated URL already so maybe I could pull the number from that? I am not familiar with java script.